# Changing vertical spacing between equations

Tags: spacing, equations

I'd like to reduce vertical spacing between `dmath` equations. I don't know how spacing works here. I tried changing line spacing with `setspace` but to no effect. This is meant to be a formula sheet with many stacked equations. One of the possible ways to go about this is to use `dgroup`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
Q(\lambda,\hat{\lambda}) = -\frac{1}{2} P{(O \mid \lambda )} \sum_s \sum_m \sum_t             \gamma_m^{(s)} (t) \left( n \log(2 \pi ) + \log \left| C_m^{(s)} \right| + \left(    \mathbf{o}_t - \hat{\mu}_m^{(s)} \right) ^T C_m^{(s)-1} \left(\mathbf{o}_t -   \hat{\mu}_m^{(s)}\right) \right)
 \end{dmath}
 \begin{dmath}
Q(\lambda,\hat{\lambda}) = -\frac{1}{2} P{(O \mid \lambda )} \sum_s \sum_m \sum_t             \gamma_m^{(s)} (t) \left( n \log(2 \pi ) + \log \left| C_m^{(s)} \right| + \left(    \mathbf{o}_t - \hat{\mu}_m^{(s)} \right) ^T C_m^{(s)-1} \left(\mathbf{o}_t -   \hat{\mu}_m^{(s)}\right) \right)
 \end{dmath}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: You should make these two `dmath` equations into one `align`.

Comment: You should enclose the two `dmath` alignments inside a `dgroup*` environment. The result that's obtained, though, confirms me in the opinion that `breqn` is to be kept as far away as possible from my documents.

Comment: I agree with @egreg, I couldn't find any options at all that gave good breaks automatically for this example. Far, far better to use one of the amsmath environments and break the equations manually.

Comment: You can manually add a `\vspace{-1em}` prior to entering the 2nd `dmath` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people have mentioned `dgroup` is pretty much the only way. However, I found using `breqn` to be inconvenient. It still requires intervention, because equations are not broken up the way I would like. So, now I'm using `gather*` with `split`.